# C++ 11: Adding an int to a wchar_t

Tags: c++11, unicode, int, unicode-string, widechar

I naively added an int to a wchar_t resulting in a Visual Studio 2013 warning.

```
L'A' + 1 // next letter
```

`warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'int' to 'wchar_t', possible loss of data`

So the error is concerned that a 4 byte int is being implicitly cast to a 2 byte wchar_t. Fair enough.

What is the C++ 11 standards safe way of doing this? I'm wondering about cross-platform implications, code-point correctness and readability of doing things like: `L'A' + (wchar_t)1` or `L'A' + \U1` or whatever. What are my coding options?

Edit T+2: I presented this question to a hacker's group. Unsurprisingly, no one got it correct. Everyone agreed this is a great interview question when hiring C/C++ Unicode programmers because it's very terse and deserves a meaty conversation.

Comment: ... by any chance are you then storing the result in a `wchar_t`?  Please post http://sscce.org as `int main() { L'A'+1; }` won't reproduce your warning.

Comment: No chance at all. Temp expression.

Comment: `static_cast<wchar_t>(L'A' + 1)`

Comment: @Igor but the OP says they are not converting the result of the expression to a `wchar_t`.  If so, why would converting it to a `wchar_t` explicitly  help?

Comment: @Yakk: I'm pretty sure the OP is then passing the result of the expression to a function declared to take `wchar_t`, as in `f(L'A' + 1)`. Hence 'argument' in the warning message.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Hey, I asked him right out if he's storing it as a `wchar_t`.  Maybe function arguments aren't "storage" as far as the OP is concerned?

Comment: @igor is correct. The temp expression is used as an argument to a func similar to his example. Please note, this is not a question of Why -- i stated why. The question is of how to-do or correct practice. I also show two solutions but there may be better solutions.

Comment: Have you tried `L'A' + wchar_t(1)`?

Comment: @Biffen, while L'A' + wchar_t(1) works, it would not work for L'A' + wchar_t(-1) where wchar_t is unsigned and sizeof(int) > sizeof(wchar_t). I didn't know wchar_t(1) was valid syntax -- learned something today, thanks.

Comment: @BSalita It's an oft-forgotten syntax, sort of a constructor. How about `wchar_t('A' - 1)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until I see a more elegant answer, which I hope there is, I'll go with this pattern:

```
(wchar_t)(L'A' + i)
```

I like this pattern because `i` can be negative or positive and it will evaluate as expected. My original notion to use `L'A' + (wchar_t)i` is flawed if `i` is negative and `wchar_t` is unsigned. I'm assuming here that `wchar_t` is implementation dependent and could be signed.

Comment: Whether `wchar_t` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.  But even if it is unsigned, `L'A' + (wchar_t)(-1)` is still the wide character before `L'A'`.

Comment: @aschepter, not if `wchar_t(-1)` is unsigned and `sizeof(int) > sizeof(wchar_t)`. Right? Hmmm, I guess I'm not sure if the result of the addition may be an int or must remain wchar_t.

Answer (score 1):

When you add two integral values together, such that both values can fit within an `int`, they are added as `int`s.

If you require an `unsigned int` to fit one of them, they are instead added as `unsigned int`s.

If those are not big enough, bigger types can be used.  It gets complicated, and it changes by standard revision if I remember rightly (there where some rough spots).

Now, addition with `int`s is unspecified if it overflows.  Addition with `unsigned int`s is guaranteed to wrap mod some power of two.

When you convert an `int` or an `unsigned int` to a signed type, if it doesn't fit the result is unspecified.  If it does fit, it fits.

If you convert an `int` or `unsigned int` to an unsigned type, the value that can be represented equal to the source mod some power of two (fixed for the given unsigned type) is the result.

Many popular C++ compilers and hardware return the same bit pattern for `int` as they would for `unsigned int` interpreted by 2s complement logic, but that is not required by the standard.

So `L'A' + 1` involves converting L'A' to an `int`, adding `1` as an `int`.

If we add the missing bit:

```
wchar_t bob = L'A' + 1;
```

we can see where the warning occurs.  The compiler sees someone converting an `int` to a `wchar_t` and warns them.  (this makes more sense when the values in question are not compile time constants)

If we make it explicit:

```
wchar_t bob = static_cast<wchar_t>(L'A' + 1);
```

the warning (probably?  hopefully?) goes away.  So long as the right hand side results in being in the range of valid `wchar_t` values, you are golden.

If instead you are doing:

```
wchar_t bob = static_cast<wchar_t>(L'A' + x);
```

where `x` is an `int`, if `wchar_t` is signed you could be in trouble (unspecified result if `x` is large enough!), and if it unsigned you could still be somewhat surprised.

A nice thing about this `static_cast` method is that unlike `(wchar_t)x` or `wchar_t(x)` casts, it won't work if you accidentally feed pointers into the cast.

Note that casting `x` or `1` is relatively pointless, unless it quiets the compiler, as the values are always up-converted (logically) into `int`s prior to `+` operating (or `unsigned int`s if `wchar_t` is unsigned and the same size as an `int`).  With `int` significantly larger than `wchar_t` this is relatively harmless if `wchar_t` is unsigned, as the back-conversion is guaranteed to do the same thing as adding in `wchar_t` mod its power of two, and if `wchar_t` is signed leaving the gamut gives an unspecified result anyhow.

So, cast the result using `static_cast`.  If that doesn't work, use a bitmask to explicitly clear bits you won't care about.

Finally, VS2013 uses 2s complement math for `int`.  So `static_cast<wchar_t>(L'A' + x)` and `static_cast<wchar_t>( L'A' + static_cast<wchar_t>(x))` always produce the same values, and would do so if `wchar_t` was replaced with `unsigned short` or `signed short`.

This is a poor answer: it needs curation and culling.  But I'm tired, and it might be illuminating.

Comment: We need more eyes on your answer. I don't think you are correct for Visual Studio for `(L'A' + x)` where `x` is > SHORT_MAX. As you say "it needs curation and culling".

Comment: @bslita `(a+(b%k))%k`=`(a+b)%k`.  And vs does sign extension on signed values, but otherwise treats them the same as unsigned, which is math mod `2^(8*sizeof(T))` for type `T`.  Can you produce a single counter example?  I could be wrong.

Comment: `static_cast<wchar_t>( L'A' + static_cast<wchar_t>(x))` won't work. Equivalent is `(short)(L'A' + (short)0xffff0000)`.